# Delaunay triangulation from convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation, delaunay

I need to write some codes on computational geometry and parallelize them using openMP.So far, I have finished convex hull and closest pair of points.I need to write the delaunay triangulation divide and conquer code.But I dont have much time.I read somewhere that delaunay triangulation can be easily implemented if the convex hull can be calculated.So if anyone can provide me the serial code for DT or atleast let me know how i could generate the delaunay triangulation  from convex hull, i could write the code and parallelize it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read somewhere that delaunay triangulation can be easily implemented if the convex hull can be calculated.

This is true, but the precise statement is that the *2D Delaunay triangulation* can be easily constructed if a *3D convex hull* implementation is available.  Knowing the 2D hull does not help much with constructing the Delaunay triangulation (DT), besides giving you a few edges of the DT (each hull edge is an edge of the DT).

Assuming you have not implemented the 3D hull (which is quite tricky), then you need to attack
the Delaunay triangulation separately.

Comment: Yeah i get it now.thanks for clearing things.Can you refer some links where i can find the 2d implementation of the de wall algorithm.thanks again

Comment: What i'm lookin for is a simple divide and conquer algorithm to implement delaunay triangulation.It doesnt have to be efficient(like using hash list and uniform grid in case of de wall),it just has to be very simple.My main concern is to efficiently parallelize it.Is it possible to implement de wall algo by using stacks/queues instead of hash lists and without uniform grid too?

Comment: @haxor: Sorry, I am not familiar with that specific algorithm.  I am familiar with, and indeed have implemented, straightforward divide-and-conquer for the hull.  It is pretty easy.  You just need to find a common upper tangent between two horizontally separated hulls, and the rest is easy.

Comment: well,hull isnt the problem.delaunay triangulation is.Could you suggest where i could find a good explanation of a simple divide and conquer algorithm for implementing delaunay triangulation.

Comment: See "Divide-and-conquer for Voronoi diagrams revisited" by Aicholzer et al. [link here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772110000325).

Comment: Using the naive delaunay triangulation algorithm(pg 187) in your book "Computational Geometry In C,2nd ed",how do i remove the degeneracies ? I was thinking of storing all the triangulation edges and checking whether they intersect with each other.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

QHull is pretty much the standard library many people use: http://www.qhull.org/html/qhull.htm
Perhaps you can use it as a reference implementation, if you really want to reimplement this.

Comment: hey thanks for answering, but i would rather prefer something other than Qhull.I am interested in the DeWall algo.Any ideas regarding that

Comment: @haxor I don't know, but google reveals this implementation of DeWall: http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/activities/geometryegraphics/dewall.html which you can download and look at the source.